# FireMonkey, IOS FMX.Listview

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I need to access (ShowMessage) of  the Text propertys of the FOOTER, HEADER, ITEMS in the FMX.ListView control.

[image]

The 1,2,3 are the Headers (ItemText).

How can I do a simple show message to show these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by checking the Purpose property of each item in the list, for example :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var I : Integer;
begin

 for I := 0 to ListView1.ItemCount - 1
 do begin
    case ListView1.Items.Item[I].Purpose
    of
       TListItemPurpose.None:   ShowMessage('Item: ' + ListView1.Items.Item[I].Text);
       TListItemPurpose.Header: ShowMessage('Header: ' + ListView1.Items.Item[I].Text);
       TListItemPurpose.Footer: ShowMessage('Footer: ' + ListView1.Items.Item[I].Text);
    end;
 end;

end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much been having a hard time figuring that out.